# In laravel 4, How to render in template (blade) plain css or js from file?

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have in `laravel/app/views/css` a file `style.css` and this is not public, how can i use this in template using `<style></style>`. I **don't** want this to be a link (`<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">`), just plain text inside html.

i kwon how to do this with blade:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but i want to learn how to do something like this from file:

```
<style>
//css code
</style>
```

with TWIG i know i can do this:  `<style> {{ include(//link to css file) }} </style>`

The only way i know i can do this with blade is:

rename the `login.css` to `login.blade.php`

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    @include('css.login')
</style>
```

have another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need another way, this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is pretty fine, and I would prefer your approach, but if you want to alter you can use something like this, too:

```
<style> <?php include_once('./app/views/css/style.css'); ?></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Meroje and Arda said those are the out-of-box ways to handle it. [You could add new Blade Extension](http://blog.zerilliworks.net/blog/2013/07/10/blade-extensions-in-laravel-4/) for handling that use case, so then you could say for example `@include_css('style.css')` and that's it. You could even output the `<style>...</style>` surrounding the style =)